# What's the best way to validate non-entity fields in a form in Symfony2?

Tags: validation, symfony

As the title suggests, I have a choice field (radio html input) in my form which must have a selection before the user is allowed to proceed.

I have tried adding the validation into my `validation.yml` file in the bundle (throws an error saying that the field is not a valid entity field), and I have also tried the adding a validator directly in the form code, but received an Exception because the validator classes don't implement the `FormValidatorInterface` (code is below).

```
$builder->addValidator(new  CallbackValidator(function(FormInterface $form) {
     if(!$form['has_subalbums']->getData())
     {
         $form->addError(new FormError('Please indicate sub albums'));
     }
}));
```

What is the correct way to validate non-entity fields?

Comment: See the perfect answer here for Symfony 2.1:

[Symfony 2 : Add a custom form element, not in an Entity][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10950203/354578

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

> use Symfony\Component\Form as Form; [...]
>
> ```
>  $builder->addValidator(new Form\CallbackValidator(function($form) {
>  if(!$form['has_subalbums']->getData())
>  {
>      $form->addError(new Form\FormError('Please indicate sub albums'));
>  }
>  }));
> ```

Comment: This is now deprecated in Symfony 2.1. Is there a way to do this in Symfony 2.1?

Answer (score 2):

You can find an answer here:

- [Using a Form without a Class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class)
- [Symfony2 Famous Ozmerk’s Form Model Pattern](http://www.craftitonline.com/2011/07/symfony2-famous-ozmerks-form-model-pattern/)

Comment: +1 for the Form model Pattern. It's really neat once you get the idea!

Comment: +1 for posting about the form model pattern, although in this case I think it might be a little extravagant for this one situation.