# Symfony 2 : Add a custom form element, not in an Entity

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I work with Symfony2 and I would like to create a registration form.
I don't want to use FOSUserBundle.

So, I create an Entity Account (with fields : username, password, email...) and I create the form :

```
 $account = new Account();

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($account)
  ->add('username',         'text', array('label' => 'Nom de compte :'))
  ->add('password',    'password', array('label' => 'Mot de passe :'))
  ->add('email',            'email', array('label' => 'Adresse email :'))
  ->getForm();
```

Now, I want to add a confirmation field for the password.
But, when I try to add a field with add() method, for example "password_confirmation"
I have this :

> Neither property "password_confirmation" nor method "getPasswordConfirmation()" nor method "isPasswordConfirmation()" exists in class "App\FrontBundle\Entity\Account"

How can I add a custom field ? And after, how to valid it ?

Thank you.
BR.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In a normal situation, you'd need to explicitly specify that *password_confirmation* isn't part of the entity, using the [property_path](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/field.html#property-path) option.

```
->add('password_confirmation', 'password', array('property_path' => false))
```

And then to validate it with a [CallBackValidator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html).

**But**, in this specific case, where you want to repeat a field, the [repeated](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html) widget can do that for you.

```
->add('password_confirmation', 'repeated', array(
    // See the docs :)
));
```

Comment: This is no longer valid as of Symfony 2.1. You should use 'mapped' => false instead, eg:

`->add('password_confirmation', 'password', array('mapped' => false));`

Answer (score 67):

An update for Symfony 2.1:

`property_path` has been deprecated and instead you should use [mapped](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped). The syntax remains the same:

```
->add('password_confirmation', 'password', array('mapped' => false))
```